# What is the type of character like "&#64;" and how to convert to ASCII

Tags: c#

Can you any one tell me what is the type of `"&#64;"` this kind of characters. Is is called Unicode character?

I also want to have full set of this type of characters and also I want to know how to convert them to ascii in C#.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks all of you for your valuable answers/comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&#64;` Is HTML Encoding for `@` It's also known as `HTML Entities`.

In C# you can use the [httpUtilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) class to decode and encode values.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence

`&#64;`

is HTML encoding for the character with decimal value 64, which is the `@` character.

(Note if you type that sequence into your question without the backticks, it is translated to the @)

You can find out what the actual character is meant to be using a unicode table.  The following one is handy because it also provides decimal values:

http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html

Comment: I thought they are called htmlentities.

Answer (score 2):

SO automatically answered your question before my edit - this is HTML encoding for "@" character.

```
var decoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#64;")
```